# Magento 2 : Replace labels in invoice pdf

Tags: magento-2.1

I am new in magento 2. I am facing problem in replacing labels in pdf invoice. I need to replace "Tax" label by "GST" label which is present at right hand bottom. I have wasted more than 6 hours on this but not getting any solution.

Please help me in this.

Comment: You need to change everywhere or only pdf invoice?

Comment: Currently I need on invoice wherever Tax label appears. After that will move for everythere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `tax` keyword in first column and add `GST` keyword in second column in below file, That's it

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. One more query. I have made this change now for invoice pdf. I need to make same changes "Tax" => "GST" in whole site. Should I follow same approach like above?

Comment: @Mahesh, above changed is for apply to whole the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate "Tax" for that ,
Create file "en_US.csv" as like:

```
|__/app
 |__/design
   |__/frontend
     |__/Vendor
       |__/themename
         |__/i18n
           |-- en_US.csv
```

And in csv file add like : "Tax","GST"

for more about language pack and translation :http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html